# Strange Spring Batch exception, something I did wrong?

Tags: spring-batch

I can break a working test with this diff:

```
-   protected void ingest(String filename) throws Exception {
+   protected JobExecution ingest(String filename) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file", filename).toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        Assertions.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
+       return jobExecution;
    }
```

This yields:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create job execution from method: ingest
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobScopeTestExecutionListener.getJobExecution(JobScopeTestExecutionListener.java:128)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobScopeTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(JobScopeTestExecutionListener.java:77)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching arguments found for method: ingest
    at org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.HippyMethodInvoker.findMatchingMethod(HippyMethodInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:190)
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobScopeTestExecutionListener.getJobExecution(JobScopeTestExecutionListener.java:124)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace or do proper formatting as currently it is totally unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a `JobScopeTestExecutionListener`. This listener looks for a factory method that creates a `JobExecution`, using it as the context for each test method. There is a note about this in the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components). The factory method is detected by its signature (it must return a `JobExecution`), but the docs are not precise enough about the signature of the factory method, which should not accept any parameter.

That's why when you change the signature of `ingest` to return a `JobExecution`, the test fails.